# Excel how to loop through data all in one column

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I currently have a very large data set and I am trying to reorganize them as described below:

Current:

A

B

C

(empty row here)

A

B

C

D

empty row here

A

B

C

There is either ABC or ABCD all in column A, followed by an empty row

and I am trying to format like this

ABC

ABCD

ABC
...

I cannot figure out how to do this if anyone can help me out, this is all being done on excel

Comment: Please provide what cope you have tried thusfar.  Remember, StackOverflow is a collaborative site dedicated to helping with *specific* coding issues, not a code-for-you service.  If you need help getting started, use the Macro Recorder under the Developer tab in Excel.  For a hint in the right direction, look into For loops, or For Each loops.

Comment: ive been trying to use loops to go down the column until it hits a blank space, which I can do, my problem is how do I assign the 1st value to be adjacent to the column spot, and the 2nd to be adjacent to the 1st value and so forth

Comment: Same as deleting or inserting work, you want to go in reverse order (Step -1) and move related data.  You will mos tlikely want to store the rows (top and bottom of each section you're grouping) so you can then perform actions on said rows.

Comment: Please make sure the text you posted is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A starting place for you (taken from: [Excel VBA, capture first "start" value and last "end" value per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058785/excel-vba-capture-first-start-value-and-last-end-value-per-group/49058893#49058893))

```
 Dim a as Long, b as Long, i as Long, lr as Long
 lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
 For i = 2 to lr
     If cells(i,1).value = cells(i+1,1).value then
          If a = 0 then
              a = i + 1
          End If
     Else
          If a > 0 AND b = 0 then
              b = i + 1
          End If             
     End If
     If b > 0 AND a > 0 Then
         'perform action on range(cells(a,2),cells(b,2))), etc.
         a = 0 'resets for next grouping
         b = 0 'resets for next grouping
    End If
Next i
a = 0
b = 0
```